# Coldfusion download file

Tags: javascript, ajax, coldfusion, cfml, coldfusion-11

I want to download file via ajax get request which calls coldfusion function, but the problem is that in "network" tab in dev tools I can "see" the content, but it doesn't download it.

Here is my coldfusion function which is stored in cfc:

```
<cffunction name="download" access="remote" output="true">
    <cfset file_name = "Test.xlsx">
    <cfheader name='Content-Disposition' value='attachment; filename=#file_name#' charset='utf-8'> 
    <cfcontent type="application/msexcel" file="#file_name#" deletefile="false">
</cffunction>
```

Here is my ajax call:

```
<script>
        $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: "ses/dev.cfc",
            data: {
                method: 'download'
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("Downloaded");
            },
            error: 'Not downloaded'
        });
    </script>
```

And here is my result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8qNy.jpg

Comment: If you want this to download the file to your computer, you need to make an HTTP GET request to the server, not an XMLHttpRequest (Ajax) GET.

Comment: I think you will need to do this as a .cfm and not as a function in a .cfc.

Comment: Why are you complicating a simple matter of file downloading by adding javascript to the equation?

Comment: @DanBracuk Can I ask you how would you do it ?

Comment: I would have a Cold Fusion page (.cfm) where the last two lines of code are the `<cfheader>` and `<cfcontent>` tags.

Comment: It is not really specific to ColdFusion. Search the archives for jQuery ajax download. Lots of threads explaining the reason and possible alternatives, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax

Comment: @Leigh it's specific to ColdFusion if yoiu're trying to download a file from a folder outside of the webroot and if you need to verify the user's logged in and has access to the file.

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno - True. I just meant the general issue is not CF specific. Least not from what they posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll that downloading function should be remove inside Ajax, and move that to different process... maybe call it on different URL something like this:

`http://websiteurl.com/download.php?file=xxxxx&sec_string=xxxxxx` etc

I hope this make sense :)

Comment: Yeah this works, but I still don't have a clue why it was not working